# Using withParentRev to overwrite file using Dropbox API for Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to Dropbox and overwrite the previous file with the same name, but I can't quite understand how to use the metadata appropriately. I based my code on the Dropbox examples, so the restClients remain as shown there.

This is part of my code:

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:filename];
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

I know the `withParentRev`parameter should be changed, but I do not what to change it to. Where is the metadata saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `restClient:loadedMetadata:` delegate method, you get the parent revision from the `DBMetadata` object using the `rev` property.